# looking for better way to fetch all Data Types and prepare a kind of dictionary with data type as key and a filter list as value

Tags: c#

I have below class structure and a list of `CollectionInstance`

```
public class CollectionInstance
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<CollectionProperty> CollectionProperties { get; set; }
}

public class CollectionProperty
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }
    public string DataType { get; set; }
}
```

Here is list of `CollectionInstance`. Currently it has only two data types double and string, but I have more data types

```
var lstCollectionInstances = new List<CollectionInstance>
        {
            new CollectionInstance
            {
                Name = "A",
                CollectionProperties = new List<CollectionProperty>
                {
                    new CollectionProperty {Name = "P1", Value = 10, DataType = "Double"}
                }
            },
            new CollectionInstance
            {
                Name = "A",
                CollectionProperties = new List<CollectionProperty>
                {
                    new CollectionProperty {Name = "P2", Value = "H1", DataType = "String"}
                }
            },
            new CollectionInstance
            {
                Name = "B",
                CollectionProperties = new List<CollectionProperty>
                {
                    new CollectionProperty {Name = "P1", Value = 20, DataType = "Double"}
                }
            },
            new CollectionInstance
            {
                Name = "B",
                CollectionProperties = new List<CollectionProperty>
                {
                    new CollectionProperty {Name = "P2", Value = "H2", DataType = "String"}
                }
            },
        };
```

Now my goal to fetch all the different data type and filter list of `CollectionInstance` based on the data type. May be a dictionary or could be other collection as well, where I should store data type as key and filtered `CollectionInstance` as a value.

I tried below, but what could be the best way?

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<CollectionInstance>>();

        var dataTypesGroups = lstCollectionInstances
            .SelectMany(x => x.CollectionProperties).GroupBy(x => x.DataType);

        foreach (var dataType in dataTypesGroups)
        {
            dictionary.Add(dataType.Key, GetFilterData(lstCollectionInstances, dataType.Key));
        }


private static List<CollectionInstance> GetFilterData(IEnumerable<CollectionInstance> lst, string dataType)
    {
        return lst.Where(x => x.CollectionProperties.Any(y => y.DataType == dataType)).ToList();
    }
```

Comment: Can you define "best"? Why didn't you just make a dictionary to start with? (They have initializers too) (LINQ also has a toDixtionary). What is the goal here?

Comment: here there are multiple time we'are hitting `lstCollectionInstances`, one time for to grab all data type, one time to filter string, one time for double. can we minimize it?

Comment: Just hit them once then, with a solution that uses two loops (posted)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could keep reference to parent `CollectionInstance` when grouping and reuse that when selecting results:

```cs
lstCollectionInstances
        .SelectMany(x => x.CollectionProperties, (i, c) => new {CollectionInstance = i, CollectionProperty = c})
        .GroupBy(x => x.CollectionProperty.DataType)
        .ToDictionary(c => c.Key, c => c.Select(d => d.CollectionInstance) )
```

**UPD**
here we leverage this overload of [`.SelectMany()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_SelectMany__3_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___1___System_Func___0___1___2__). So Instead of `List<CollectionProperty>` you end up having `List<Tuple<CollectionInstance,CollectionProperty>>` *(well, i opted for anonymous type, but this does not matter much)*. You basically enhance each child object with reference to its parent. And since all these are just references - you don't trade a lot of memory for having it. 
And when you group it - you get an option to not select the `CollectionProperty`, but rather the parent object directly.

I hope this makes sense

Comment: super. Thanks. Could you please explain it more?

Comment: Thanks, appreciated

Comment: The only problem with this solution is that it needed explaining more; a future developer might read this and also wonder what the heck it does. Never forget the value of implementing easy to understand solutions; either comment this or comment in a link to this question

Comment: @CaiusJard I 100% agree with your point - this definitely was not beginner-friendly at first. I however felt the OP was able to use that given OP's command of `SelectMany()` in the first place. I'm happy to spend a little bit more time making this answer better - which area do you think can be improved?

Comment: @timor Oh; I don't think it can in and of itself; it's brilliant - it's just that being brilliant is the flaw (and you can't take it away!). My final "never forget" was a comment to the OP, sorry I should have made that clear

Answer (score 1):

Build a dictionary that for each data type stores a list of instances with a property of the key data type.

```
var result = instances
    .SelectMany(x => x.Properties)
    .Select(x => x.DataType)
    .Distict()
    .ToDictionary(x => x, x => GetInstancesWithPropertyOfType(x, instances));
```

Given the following is defined:

```
public class Instance
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Property> Properties { get; set; }
}

public class Property
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }
    public string DataType { get; set; }
}

List<Instance> GetInstancesWithPropertyOfType(string dataType, IEnumerable<Instance> instances) => 
    instances.Where(x => x.Properties.Any(y => y.DataType == dataType)).ToList();
```

Comment: what is getkey, getValue ? it's give me compile error here

Comment: This is my mistake. Edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Personally think that using LINQ on this just makes it more unreadable and harder to understand. This is basically a two loop operation; `for each x in instances/foreach y in x.properties/add x to dictionary indexed by y.z` and would be most easily understood by keeping it as such. This minimizes the amount of work done by the framework too; here we create no unnecessary extra objects, lists, groupings etc in the quest to enumerate a 2-deep object hierarchy and create a dictionary, and even a coder who never saw LINQ can understand it:

```
    var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<CollectionInstance>>();

    foreach (var ci in lstCollectionInstances){
        foreach(var cp in ci.CollectionProperties){
            if(!dictionary.ContainsKey(cp.DataType))
                dictionary[cp.Key] = new List<CollectionInstance>();
            dictionary[cp.Key].Add(ci);
        }
    }
```

LINQ is a hammer; not every problem is a nail